# how to process sql query inside for loop synchronouysly and array gets empty outside a function

Tags: node.js, express

```
var feedData = [];
var listFeedQuery = pgFormat("select * from feedList where shopId=%L",shopId);
model.client.query(listFeedQuery,function(err,result){
    if(result.rows.length > 0){
        var triggerImageQuery = function(start,length,callback) {
        var feedInfo = result.rows[start];
        var imgQuery = pgFormat("select * from feedImages where feedId=%L",feedInfo.feedid);
        model.client.query(imgQuery,function(err,result){
            if(result.rows.length > 0){
                var imgArr =[];
                for(var j=0;j<result.rows.length;j++){
                    var image = "http://"+config.host+":"+config.port+"/"+result.rows[j].imageurl;
                    imgArr.push(image);
                }
                feedData.push(feedInfo);
                feedData.push(imgArr);
            }
            else{
                feedData.push(feedInfo);
            }
console.log(feedInfo); // feedInfo have value
       });
            console.log(feedInfo); // feedInfo gets empty here
           callback({'success':'1','result':{feedData},errorMessage:'No'});

            if(start < length) {
                start++;
                triggerImageQuery(start, length-1);
            }
        }
        triggerImageQuery(0, result.rows.length,function(result){
            res.json(result);
        });
    }
    else{
      res.json({'success':'0','result':{},'errorMessage':'No feed available from the shop'});
    } 
});
```

feedData array is looks empty outside of a function?

its into looping(var feedInfo = result.rows[start];), so i unable to use the callback inside model.client.query. if i have callback inside  model.client.query it will show the first set of details and return typeError : callback is not a function.

Comment: what is the issue? Is this not logging correct data `console.log(feeds,imgArr);` ?

Comment: yes, the last value of the feed are repeating. for example i have feed values like 28,29,30. but the output looks like all the feed's data as 30

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes. I have replaced the `for...loop` with a function logic.

```
var feedData = [];

var verifyShopQuery = pgFormat("select * from feedList where shopId=%L",shopId);
model.client.query(verifyShopQuery,function(err,result){
    if(result.rows.length > 0){

            var triggerImageQuery = function(start, length) {
                var feeds = result.rows[start];
                var imgQuery = pgFormat("select * from feedImages where feedId=%L",feeds.feedid);
                model.client.query(imgQuery,function(err,result){
                    if(result.rows.length > 0){
                        var imgArr =[];
                        for(var j=0;j<result.rows.length;j++){
                            imgArr.push(result.rows[j].imageurl);
                        }
                        console.log(feeds,imgArr);
                        if(start < length) {
                            start++;
                            triggerImageQuery(start, length);
                        }
                    }
                });
            };

            triggerImageQuery(0, result.rows.length);

        }
    else{
        res.json({'success':'0','result':{},'errorMessage':'invalid shopId'});
    }
```

Comment: Great to know it worked for you. Please accept the answer.

Comment: i am facing one more issue on the same like, i am adding data into an array, but outside of the db's function, the array is getting empty? here i am adding the feedData.push(feeds,imgArr); but if i am print outside the array is empty.

Comment: Updated my answer. See where I have declared `feedData `. That way you can print the value outside.

Comment: yes i have tried that too.. but it is empty, i want to gather all the data into an array and have to send via response

Comment: Can you please provide your updated code! So that I can look into it.

Comment: same like before, it is printing all the feedInfo in the console, but in callback it returns only the first set of data and throw TypeError : callback is not a function.

Comment: i want to store all the feed info into the feedData and have to send it via callback to response.

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/6c68ee5g/1/). I have updated some codes.

Comment: same like before TypeError : callback is not a function.. Thank u very much for your effort bro.